# svn build and release

Tags: svn

This is the scenario

I use SVN as my code repository. I have a separate Windows build machine that uses ant scripts to generate the final "jar" file. The automated build script checks out the latest version of the code and does the build.  Once build is done - a tag is created (in the format YYYYMMDD-build 1.01.jar). We also store the build file(the final jar) in subversion. 
Any properties files, configuration files, or database scripts(related to the issue) are checked into subversion, but they are currently not included in the build package.

Now we have 2 new requirements -

1. To Include in the build - the specific versions of the properties files or configuration files or database scripts(related to the issue)that are checked into subversion(example version 1 of a.properties file, version 3 of x.sql script etc.)
2. To create a new build package to include the changed version of a file like a properties file (eveything else should remain the same as the previous build)

What are the best practices for incorporating the above requirements?

Appreciate  your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your Ant build script to use SvnAnt (http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html), or update it to make the proper command line calls, to add the files to version control prior to the copy.  So when you tag your build, the files you added to the working copy would be included in the tag but not the location where the tag was checked out from.  That would take care of #1.

For #2, you could also script this in Ant such that a file was updated to include the revision information.  Again, SvnAnt would help you here.

Using SvnAnt gives you access to a lot of Subversion command and working copy information and from what I can tell, this is all you'd need to address your needs.

Comment: To clarify - the scripts were created by someone in this position earlier. I do notice svnant jar embedded in the script - but I am not sure how to go about to iplement your suggestions.....

Comment: I'm sure you're qualified to handle this.  Taking an Ant build script that does everything for you and changing it to handle new criteria shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Its not the changing of the script that I need help with ....it is the process - Is it good practice to keep creating a build for every small change...... that where the confusion comes

Comment: I personally do not agree with versioning each build or even version build artifact.  Versioning build artifacts is a waste in my opinion because version control is for versioning things and, well, your build artifact isn't going to change.  Even tagging builds isn't necessary since you can access repository paths using a timestamp so if you built at this specific time, you can get the exact same sources used to build without a tag.